# How to put limit on slider

Tags: templates

My question is, how do I put a limit on the amount of featured content that shows up on my slider on the front page.

I'm using Dynamic News theme and it has a slider built in. However I want to limit on how many pieces of featured content actually show up on the slider.

The site is http://www.kurdang.com

As you can you on the front page it has like 20 slides but I would like to reduce that to like 5.

Could anybody please help or lead me to the right direction.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You should ask the theme developer, it depends how it is setup. I mean the WP answer would be 'posts_per_page' => 5, within the slider query array but without the slider code it would be hard to tell you what to do and where to do it

Comment: I've tried contacting the theme developer but unfortunately haven't received a reply. And where could I pull the slider code from for you to have a look at? Thanks

Comment: Add the slider code to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed the Lite version of this theme on a test site and dug around. The function that generates the slider doesn't provide any useful filters. However, it does store the IDs of the featured posts in a transient, so you could use the `pre_set_site_transient_' . $transient` and `transient_' . $transient` filters to reduce the number of posts. It also respects the value 'max_posts' as declared in the theme, so you could replace this. Both would required creating a child theme (or, in the case of the former, a plugin that allows you to add hooks would also suffice).

Transient method:

```
add_filter( 'pre_set_site_transient_featured_content_ids', 'wpse174427_transient_method' );
add_filter( 'transient_featured_content_ids', 'wpse174427_transient_method' );
function wpse174427_transient_method( $value ) {
  return array_slice( $value, 0, 5 );
}
```

Theme support method:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse174427_themesupport_method', 11 );
function wpse174427_themesupport_method() {
  remove_theme_support( 'featured-content' );
  add_theme_support( 'featured-content', array( 'featured_content_filter' => 'dynamicnews_get_featured_content', 'max_posts' => 5 ) );
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the great info and going through the theme. But where would I add those 2 snippets of codes to? What files? Thanks

Comment: FIXED IT! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! YOU ARE THE BEST HAHA!!!